# Как получить самое большое и маленькое число одного типа в объекта?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var object = { 
    "N102 - Number 102": {name: "1N02 - Number 102"},
    "B152 - Bar 152": {name: "B152 - Bar 152"},
    "N104 - Number 104": {name: "N104 - Number 104"},
    "A126 - A 126": {name: "A126 - A 126"},
    "N100 - Number 100": {name: "N100 - Number 100"},
    "A156 - A 156": {name: "A156 - A 156"},
    "N155 - Number 155": {name: "N155 - Number 155"},
    "C110 - C 110": {name: "C110 - C 110"}
};
```

Этим способом я получая самое большое и самое маленькое число из всего объекта:

```
var a = Object.keys(object).map(x => +x.match(/\d+/));
console.log(Math.min(...a));
console.log(Math.max(...a));
```

Помогите получить только самое маленькое и большое число из ключей, содержащих букву N и слово Number. В данном случаи это должно быть 100 и 104.

Comment: @Grundy, вопрос не про мин-макс, а про фильтрацию по названию ключа. Если закрывать дублем, то явно не этим.

Comment: @teran, на как бы меняется метод map и регулярка - и все остальное как есть

Comment: А что делать-то @Grundy? На что изменить map и регулярку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для поиска только на определенном наборе из сходных данных, их нужно предварительно отфильтровать.

Например с помощью метода [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var a = Object.keys(object)
              .filter( x => x.indexOf('N') > -1 ) // выбираем элементы начинающиеся на N
              .map(x => +x.match(/\d+/));

console.log(Math.min(...a));
console.log(Math.max(...a));
```

---

Для поиска min и max элементов за один проход можно воспользоваться обычным циклом `for`, либо [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Например так:

```js
var object = {
  "N102 - Number 102": {
    name: "1N02 - Number 102"
  },
  "B152 - Bar 152": {
    name: "B152 - Bar 152"
  },
  "N104 - Number 104": {
    name: "N104 - Number 104"
  },
  "A126 - A 126": {
    name: "A126 - A 126"
  },
  "N100 - Number 100": {
    name: "N100 - Number 100"
  },
  "A156 - A 156": {
    name: "A156 - A 156"
  },
  "N155 - Number 155": {
    name: "N155 - Number 155"
  },
  "C110 - C 110": {
    name: "C110 - C 110"
  }
};

var a = Object.keys(object)
  .reduce((acc, cur) => {
    var match = cur.match(/^N(\d+)/);
    if (!match) return acc; // если не подходит = оставляем как есть

    var curNum = +match[1];
    return { // иначе обновляем min и max
      min: acc.min > curNum ? curNum : acc.min,
      max: acc.max < curNum ? curNum : acc.max
    }
  }, {
    min: Infinity,
    max: -Infinity
  })
console.log(a);
```

Comment: не думаю, что комбинировать `filter` и `map` хорошая идея, для этого есть метод `reduce`. Например, `var a = Object.keys(object).reduce((res, x) => x.match(/N\d+/) ? res.concat(+x.match(/\d+/)) : res, []);`

Comment: Всё брат, огромнейщеее спасибо!

Comment: Vladimir, благодарю за хороший совет.

Comment: @Vladimir, если уж использовать `reduce`, то можно сразу и min/max искать.

Comment: @Grundy, как это осущеставлить?

Comment: @AlisaBondarchuk `Object.keys(object).reduce((res, x) => {
 var number = x.match(/N\d+/) ? +x.match(/\d+/) : undefined;
 if (!res.max || res.max < number) res.max = number;
 if (!res.min || res.min > number) res.min = number;
 return res;
}, {});`

Comment: Круто сработало, спасибо братан.